# Can I identify users who use my app daily/weekly/monthly with google analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I would like to segment my android app users into those that use the app daily/weekly/montly, etc. Is this possible with Google Analytics?

I do have a user-ID enabled profile, so the data should be there - I just don't know if there is any way to query all values of a metric (e.g. days since last visit) associated with a single user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Under **Users Overview** section, you can find Hourly/Daily/Weekly/Monthly users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, if you mean the graphs in the Audience->Overview section, this is not what I mean. The graph shows e.g. how many users opened my app in the last week (or day or month), whereas I would like to know how many users open my app at least once a week (or day or month)